# count an amount of numbers from a table cell based on a cell from another table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table from a restaurant in sql that has various products, and i have a form where theres orders, i search a table and evey order from that table appears, then i have a button where i want to calculate all prices based on what all people ordered and put the result in  a text box, heres my try:

```
   Call Conectar()
    For b = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        'SELECIONA TABELA PRODUTO PARA IR BUSCAR O PREÇO UNITARIO 

        Dim selectproduto As String = "select count(preço) as conta from Produto,pedido  where pedido.ID_Produto= '" & DataGridView1.Rows(b).Cells(1).Value() & "'"
        Dim selectprodutoCOM As New SqlCommand(selectproduto, con)
        Dim da As SqlDataReader = selectprodutoCOM.ExecuteReader
        da.Read()
        TextBox6.Text = da!conta
        da.Close()
    Next
    Call Desconectar()
```

i have on one hand, the table Produto where the price(preço) is stored, and i want to retrieve the sum of the prices based on what showing on a dgv that show content from table Pedido(order)

Comment: Use sum(preço) instead of count(preço)

Comment: it says that the varcharstring "frango" cant be turned to int

Comment: What data type is the price stored as? i.e. is it a string?

Comment: the price is stored as money

Comment: This question needs a lot more clarification. What are the columns in the tables that you are using and what are their data types? I think that this issue with "frango" is probably a different issue (since it is a varchar). Can you include some sample data?